# Custom authorize attribute in asp net core and jwt token

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, authorization

In my project, I have number of APIs using JWT token which are decorated with `[Authorize]` attribute and it run well.

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
public IActionResult GetCustomers()
{
   return Ok();
}
```

If I provide null, wrong JWT token or JWT token with not Administrator role, it return response like picture below:
[image]

But I want to custom response like that:

```
{
  "StatusCode" : 401,
  "message": "You need Administrator role"
}
```

And I follow to [this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31464359/how-do-you-create-a-custom-authorizeattribute-in-asp-net-core) to custom authorize attribute.

My custom:

```
public class ClaimRequirementAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
    {
        public ClaimRequirementAttribute(string claimType, string claimValue) : base(typeof(CustomAuthorization))
        {
            Arguments = new object[] { new Claim(claimType, claimValue) };
        }
    }


    public class CustomAuthorization : IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        readonly Claim _claim;

        public CustomAuthorization(Claim claim)
        {
            _claim = claim;
        }

        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
        {
            var hasClaim = context.HttpContext.User.Claims.Any(c => c.Type == _claim.Type && c.Value == _claim.Value);
            if (!hasClaim)
            {
                context.Result = new ForbidResult($"You need {_claim.Value} role");
            }
        }
    }
```

And my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ClaimRequirement(ClaimTypes.Role, "Administrator")]
public IActionResult GetCustomers()
    {
       return Ok();
    }
```

But I have 2 problems:

- The first problem is that if I provide null, wrong JWT token or JWT token with not administrator role, I have this error:
  [image]
- And the second is whether there is a simple way to solve it ?

Thanks for your attention.

Edit: the first question i solved it, the solution in my comment

Comment: The first question is from my bad, I didn't read carefully about constructor of ForbidResult(). Replace to this code below to solve problem:                                                                                
 context.Result = new ObjectResult(new { 
                    message= $"You need {_claim.Value} role"
                }) { StatusCode = 403 }

Comment: What do you mean for the second question? Do you mean you want to return custom error message in another way which is more simple?

Comment: @Rena yes, I like to return custom error message, when I use default [Authorize] attribute it only return status code like the first picture. My solution is quite complicated.

Comment: Hi, actually I think your code is not complicated. For improvement, if you just want to authorize for only one action, you can inherits `Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter` to just use one custom class.